# Retrieving properties of AutoCAD object in C#

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am attempting to interrogate AutoCAD objects from C#.  I am interested in being able to grab all of the properties of a given object and output them.  For example, in the below snippit of code I am looping through all of the items on screen and just reflecting against their first-class properties.  The objects I care about often have a first-class AcadObject property which seems to hold the data I am after.  The problem is that this is a __ComObject and that many of its nested propetry objects do no provide properties via reflection.  For example, obj.AcadObject.Connectors appears to be a collection of connector objects, which I am very interested in.  I can reflect to that depth using the debugger, but from there on in I am left guessing at properties of the Connectors collection and its objects (the .Net debugger does show a Count property which tipped me off).  Using C#'s dynamic keyword and the DLR/COM binders built into .Net 4 I can probe these objects.  For example, I can use a dynamic expression to grab obj.AcadObject.Connectors[0].Name, guessing that it had a name attribute.  I am willing to use dynamic expressions to grab these properties but I need to know what the properties are in the first place.  I have researched quite a bit and seem to be missing a reference to what these objects look like.  There are a few other objects hanging off of AcadObject as well that I would like to export.

```
var currentDocument = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
var editor = currentDocument.Editor;
var database = editor.Document.Database;

var result = editor.SelectAll();

using (var transaction = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    foreach (var id in result.Value.GetObjectIds())
    {

        var obj = transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);

        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj.AcadObject).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().OrderBy(prop => prop.Name);


        writer.WriteLine("{0} ID:{1}", obj.GetType().Name, obj.Id);
        writer.WriteLine("\r\n\r\n");

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyObject = property.GetValue(obj.AcadObject);
            writer.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", property.Name, propertyObject);
        }

        writer.Write("\r\n\r\n\r\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get ALL items from Database, then use it:

```
// Get all items from drawing Database. All ObjectIds will grouped by types;
Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;           
Dictionary<string, List<ObjectId>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<ObjectId>>();
using (Transaction t = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()) {
    for (long i = db.BlockTableId.Handle.Value; i < db.Handseed.Value; i++) {
        ObjectId id = ObjectId.Null;
        Handle h = new Handle(i);
        if (db.TryGetObjectId(h, out id)) {
            string type = id.ObjectClass.Name;
            if (!dict.Keys.Contains(type))
                dict.Add(type, new List<ObjectId>());
            dict[type].Add(id);
        }
    }
    t.Commit();
}
```

Regards

Comment: I am actualying getting all of the elements I want by getting the BlockTableRecord for the ModelSpace.  My issue is enumerating all of the properties in the objects I retrieve like Width, Height, Diameter, etc.  Since I am getting various types of drawing objects (Pipe, Duct, DuctFitting, Mesh, Line, etc) I don't know what the properties are beforehand and so I want a dynamic way of looking them up.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [**MgdDbg**](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2010/02/the-stephen-and-fenton-show-adn-devcast-episode-1.html) utility to be of particular use when exploring a given drawing's Database... Depending on what you're after, and your version of AutoCAD, as Events, etc. are hard-coded rather than dynamic as Tony states [**here**](http://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=42938.msg481827#msg481827).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer but I am going to put it here so it might help someone else.  Using the immediate window I cast the obj.Acad to a dynamic, and then referenced down to the object in question such Connectors[0].  At that point I recast that to an object and was able to inspect it with a watch.  Example code as it would run in the immediate window with a debug break after the obj set:

```
dynamic acad = obj.AcadObject;
object connector0 = (object)acad.Connectors[0];
```

The best I can figure is the the COM binder for the DLR is marshaling stuff over for me, and then once I get it cast back .Net debugger can figure out the properties.  I am working on getting this discovery working with reflection...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this utility to get more informations on your COM objects: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523417/Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects